# Break when exception is thrown except for when thrown in specific place in Rider

Tags: visual-studio, rider

In Visual Studio there is a possibility to mute an exception when it happens in particular place, e.g. We are aware that there is some `NullRefereneceException` in `Calculator.cs` and we still want to catch those types of exceptions when thrown from all other places in code, but `Calculator.cs`.

How it looks like in VS:
[image]

Is such a feature available in Rider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now the feature is not yet available, but there is a [Youtrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-48593/Add-namespace-and-condition-filters-to-exception-breakpoints) for this feature.

Comment: This is an official response from JetBrains support

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a solution to your question.

The only thing I found is to not break on a specific exception type - but that's unrelated to the line.
For example, let's take the following code:

```cs
public class OtherClass
{
    public void ThrowNullReferenceException()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

With the following *Exception Settings*, the handled `NullReferenceException` gets swallowed:
[image]

Maybe you can get in contact with [Rider support](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=97145).

Comment: If this was a feature I would expect it to be available exactly in the `Breakpoints` setting that you have attached. I will try to contact the support.